# Function not working because I use dates?

Tags: vba, excel

I’m trying to write a function that depends on dates, but I can’t get it to work. Excel keeps telling me that a value that is used in this formula have the wrong data type. So it has to be the date, because I have another function that is exactly the same except for the add of a datevalue.

Someone writes a date in the Excel-cell C10 and then I wan’t the function to summarize certain numbers (predicted inflation rates, column P) from a table (on another sheet in the same workbook) in which it depends on begin-dates (column I) and end-dates (column J).

I’ve checked that Excel interprets cell C10 as a date, it does but with a serial number.

But I don’t see why that is a problem since I use it to compare with other dates (serial numbers)?

```
Public Function FetchFactorInflation(Product As String, ArgName As String) As Double

Dim Datum As Date
Datum = DateValue(Worksheets("InputTariff").Range("C10").Value)

Dim MinDatum, MaxDatum As Double
MinDatum = "<=" & Datum
MaxDatum = ">=" & Datum

FetchFactorInflation = Application.SumIfs(Worksheets("tariff").Range("P:P"), _
                        Worksheets("tariff").Range("I:I"), MinDatum, _
                        Worksheets("tariff").Range("J:J"), MaxDatum, _
                        Worksheets("tariff").Range("K:K"), Product, _
                        Worksheets("tariff").Range("L:L"), ArgName)

End Function
```

Comment: First, defining `Dim MinDatum, MaxDatum As Double ` means `MaxDatum As Double` and `MinDatum as Variant`, it needs to be `Dim MinDatum As Double, MaxDatum As Double`. Second, you need to convert the date to Double, like `MinDatum = CDbl(Datum)`. And last, when you check with your `SumIfs` function, then you will use `Worksheets("tariff").Range("I:I"), ">=" & MinDatum` .

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong data type comes from here:

```
MaxDatum = ">=" & Datum
```

MaxDatum is a double, and you are giving `>=` to it. It cannot be converted to a `Double`. Try a way around.

***The quickest solution would be to write like this:***

`Dim MinDatum, MaxDatum`

instead of

`Dim MinDatum, MaxDatum As Double`

Thus `MaxDatum` would be easily converted to what you need, because it would be variant as well as `MinDatum`.